# Sort a mutable list of objects in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

There is a class name recording with parameters song, artist, and playtime

```
class Recording {
    var title: String
    var artists: String
    var playingTime: Int

    constructor(t: String, a: String, p: Int) {
        title = t
        artists = a
        playingTime = p
    }
}
```

I have a mutable list of objects,I need to sort this based on each parameter ie song, artist, and playtime.

```
 var list = mutableListOf<Recording>(
     Recording("Sorry", "Justin Bieber", 420),
     Recording("a", "a", 1),
     Recording("b", "b", 2)
 )
```

Comment: `val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.title.toLowerCase() }, { it.artists.toLowerCase() }, {it.playingTime}))`

Answer (score 1):

You try it with either sortedWith or sortBy methods to sort a list of objects.

**Method 1:**

```
val result = list.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.title }, { it.artists }, {it.playingTime}))
```

**Method 2:**

```
val list1 = list.sortBy { it.title }
val list2 = list.sortBy { it.artists }
val list3 = list.sortBy { it.playingTime }
```

In the first method you will get a list of sorts lists and the second method will gives you the sorted results in different lists.

Comment: I think this will work fine for your case.